# Magento make payment using webservice/API by getting credit card information of customer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am providing web services of magento  for POS application.Pos app will swap customer credit card and send it to magento database.Is there any way to get customer credit card information and make payment at end of magento.In simple I want to make a API that get customer credit card information and make payment  at end of magento.**means** POS app will give credit card detail(total amount of customer shopping,customer credit card information) and I have to make payment for that amount and for that customer at end of magento.Sorry for my english.

Comment: Pls tell if someone knows how can i do it.I have wasted lot of time and applied shopping cart SOAP API for payment.but getting no solution.